# Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Retail API

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics

I'm developing a data integration application which help users to sync data from their database into

> **Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Retail**.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to find where the API is or any documents related to Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Retail. All I found are only documents for CRM.
Anyone familiar to Microsoft Dynamics 365 API, please guide me where should I start from the beginning? I would like to connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365 API to query for products & categories, or even create & delete products, update product attributes.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Won't the normal Dynamics 365 WEB API work for retail?

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593051.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 out for the WEB API.

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't.

Comment: Can you give more information about why you believe it won't? The Web API is designed for maximal interoperability in many integration scenarios.